# How do I restrict delta here?

Tags: examples, exercises

```
Prove that $\lim_{x\to 1}(x^2-1)=0$

$|(x^2 -1) -0| < \epsilon$
\\*
$|x^2 - 1| < \epsilon$
\\*
$|(x+1)(x-1)| < \epsilon$
\\*
$|x+1||x-1| < \epsilon$
```

I know I need to restrict delta now but how do I do that?

Comment: are you asking about the mathematics or how to typeset a restriction?

Comment: No - I mean that I know I can't have epsilon be in terms of x and I'm supposed to restrict delta somehow but I don't know what I'm supposed to do next.

Comment: Sorry then we'll close this question you are in entirely the wrong place, this is a typesetting forum not a math help site.

Comment: Should this posting be migrated to Math.SE?

Comment: @Mico perhaps (I don't know why we can't suggest other sites other than  meta in the off topic menu) I guess you have to flag for mod attention

Comment: @DavidCarlisle -- Thanks. I've gone ahead and set a flag for the moderators; hopefully they can migrate the posting to a more appropriate site.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle That’s because we don’t have migration paths set up. I tried to get some a while ago, but the process never really went through. See http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2411/do-we-want-more-migration-paths (and http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2454/request-for-new-migration-paths-for-tex-sx). Seeing [the relatively low number of questions migrated away](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tools/posts/migrated/stats) (10k users only), I’m not sure if we really need them, but I’d still be up for giving it another shot.